# Need date to show instead of being Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The date is showing as NULL now when the count is 0, any ideas on how to get it to show the date?

```
SELECT
    dc.dateasdate AS 'Date',
    CASE
        WHEN dc.dateasdate IS NULL THEN '0'
        ELSE COUNT(Practice)
    END AS 'Total Enquiries',
    dp.practice,
    de.Origin
FROM dim.Practice dp
LEFT JOIN fact.enquiry fe
    ON fe.PracticeSKey = dp.PracticeSKey
LEFT JOIN dim.EnquiryOrigin de
    ON de.EnquiryOriginSKey = fe.EnquiryOriginSKey
    AND de.Origin = 'Web Enquiry'
LEFT JOIN dim.Calendar dc
    ON dc.CalendarSKey = fe.EnquiryCreatedSKey
    AND dc.dateasdate = '2016-04-03'
WHERE
    de.Origin IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    dc.dateasdate,
    de.Origin,
    practice
ORDER BY dc.dateasdate, Practice
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: What is your intention? Show a `Default date` as 'Date' when dc.dateasdate  is null or **force** showing a date even it is `NULL`?

Comment: force showing the date when the date is null

Comment: sorry im using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the following:

```
case WHEN COUNT(Practice) is null THEN '0' ELSE COUNT(Practice) END AS 'Total Enquiries'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You should keep the types the same:

```
SELECT dc.dateasdate,
       (case WHEN dc.dateasdate is null THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(Practice) END) AS TotalEnquiries,
       dp.practice,
       de.Origin
```

However, the date is showing as `NULL` because the value is `NULL` in the original data.  What value do you want to show in this case?

EDIT:

You can use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(dc.dateasdate, '2016-04-03')
       (case WHEN dc.dateasdate is null THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(Practice) END) AS TotalEnquiries,
       dp.practice,
       de.Origin
. . .
```

However, I suspect that the `LEFT JOIN` is not what you really want.

Comment: i just want the date 2016-04-03

Comment: I want to show the date that we are querying, because 2016-04-03 is the sample date im using, but after im done, im going to query the last months results. so ill need to show 0 for the date we are querying

Comment: Gordon, is there any reason not to use `COALSCE()` here (just wondering) ?

Comment: only problem with SELECT COALESCE(dc.dateasdate, '2016-04-03') is that 2016-04-03 is my sample data set, eventually the script will change to query the last month's results

Comment: ok i worked it out, needed to cross join and hard code the origin 

thank you for all your help everyone